# Mind numbing SQL madness

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

This query runs on an `invoices` table to help me decide who I need to pay

Here's the base table:

The **users** table

```
+---------+--------+
| user_id |  name  |
+---------+--------+
|       1 | Peter  |
|       2 | Lois   |
|       3 | Stewie |
+---------+--------+
```

The **invoices** table:

```
+------------+---------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+
| invoice_id | user_id | currency | amount |  description  | is_paid |
+------------+---------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+
|          1 |       1 | usd      |    140 | Cow hoof      |       0 |
|          2 |       1 | usd      |     45 | Cow tail      |       0 |
|          3 |       1 | gbp      |      1 | Cow nostril   |       0 |
|          4 |       2 | gbp      |   1500 | Cow nose hair |       0 |
|          5 |       2 | cad      |      1 | eyelash       |       1 |
+------------+---------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+
```

I want a resulting table that looks like this:

```
+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
| user_id | name  | currency | SUM(amount) |
+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
|       1 | Peter | usd      |         185 |
|       2 | Lois  | gbp      |        1500 |
+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

The conditions are:

- Only consider invoices that have not been paid, so where `is_paid = 0`
- Group them by `user_id`, by `currency`
- If the `SUM(amount) < $100` for the user_id, currency pair then don't bother showing the result, since we don't pay invoices that are less than $100 (or equivalent, based on a fixed exchange rate).

Here's what I've got so far (not working -- which I guess is because I'm filtering by a GROUP'ed parameter):

```
SELECT 
  users.user_id, users.name,
  invoices.currency, SUM(invoices.amount)
FROM 
  mydb.users, 
  mydb.invoices 
WHERE 
  users.user_id = invoices.user_id AND 
  invoices.is_paid != true AND
  SUM(invoices.amount) >=
    CASE 
      WHEN invoices.currency = 'usd' THEN 100
      WHEN invoices.currency = 'gbp' THEN 155
      WHEN invoices.currency = 'cad' THEN 117
    END
GROUP BY 
  invoices.currency, users.user_id
ORDER BY 
  users.name, invoices.currency;
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **HAVING** clause instead of **SUM** in **WHERE** condition

Try this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, i.currency, SUM(i.amount) invoiceAmount 
FROM mydb.users u 
INNER JOIN mydb.invoices i ON u.user_id = i.user_id 
WHERE i.is_paid = 0
GROUP BY u.user_id, i.currency
HAVING SUM(i.amount) >= (CASE i.currency WHEN 'usd' THEN 100 WHEN 'gbp' THEN 155 WHEN 'cad' THEN 117 END)
ORDER BY u.name, i.currency;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `SUM` in a `WHERE`. Use `HAVING` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the direction cat person!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
user_id, name, currency, sum(amount) due
FROM
invoice i
JOIN users u ON i.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE
is_paid = 0 AND
GROUP BY user_id, currency
having due >= 100
```

do you store exchange rates? Multiply rates with amount to get actual amount with respect to base currency.

```
sum(amount*ex_rate) due
```

Comment: Great suggestion on storing currency rates instead of the value of 100*`currency`, thanks!

Comment: ur wc :), Yeah that's needed cause exchange rate is a variable parameter.